# Strange MySQL problems with LIMIT and JOIN

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT          s.* 
FROM            @mcmodlist_servers s
LEFT OUTER JOIN @mcmodlist_tag_server ts 
ON              ts.server_id = s.id
```

(don't mind the `@mcmodlist_` bits, it's converted by PHP into the actual table names).

When executed as written as above it gives a result of 5 records, as it should, but when I add `LIMIT 10` it suddenly returns 4.

But wait, it gets even better: If I change it to `LIMIT 12` there's suddenly 5 records again (`LIMIT 11` still returns 4).

Left outer should join only if it has a matching record and otherwise return `null`, right?

Why is `LIMIT` behaving like this? it works just fine without the `JOIN` clause

Comment: Can you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Maybe using [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Comment: @shmosel I'll give it a try

Comment: `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is kind of redundant, or syntax sugar, it is synonimus with `LEFT JOIN`, and its purpose is to NOT reduce the amound of records from the left table even if there is no matching on the right table, filling the right table results with `NULL` fields.

Comment: how are you calculating the count? maybe you are counting the rows yourself visually, but if you are wrapping the results with a `select count(field) from ( ... ) myTable` or something like that, keep in mind that the count does not increase if the field has a null value, i.e. in a result set with `5` records, a `count(myField)`, when 1 `myField` is null, will return `4`.

Comment: "Left outer should join only if it has a matching record, right?" Wrong. `INNER JOIN` only joins matching records. `LEFT JOIN` produces at least one result for every row in the left table, even if it has no match. But I don't think this is relevant to your `LIMIT` issue.

Comment: Limit without an order by doesn't make a whole lot of sense. add an order by and retry.

Comment: @xQbert limit should return a consistent number of results without an order by, although maybe not always the same records

Comment: I would tend to agree unless we are counting s.* values with null, as you pointed out, would make a difference and since the order could vary on each run, we could get 5,4,11 etc... just so long as it's below the limit.

Comment: @shmosel I tried reproducing the problem in SQLFiddle but couldn't get it to happen, no clue what I'm doing different in my own database :/

@santiagoarizti I'm simply dumping the results returned using PHP and counting them myself

@Barmar I only need a record to join if it exists, return null otherwise, only `LEFT OUTER JOIN` seemed to work for this without hiding the record entirely

Comment: That looks like a query optimizer bug... Add the EXPLAIN keyword in front of your query, and see if the plan remains the same when you change the limit.

Comment: Are `@mcmodlist_servers` and `@mcmodlist_tag_server` being replaced by simple, concrete table noms? Or are they views or subqueries?

Comment: the `@` character is replaced by PHP with the table prefix, it's using Pagekit's ORM system (Doctrine I believe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you run the query in a MySQL client, with limit 10, you will find that it is in fact returning 10 rows in the resultset.

I suspect that there are multiple rows in `@mcmodlist_tag_server` with a `server_id` that matches a row from `@mcmodlist_servers`. When there are multiple matching rows, you are going to get "duplicate" rows from `@mcmodlist_servers`.

Given that there are no columns returned from the `@mcmodlist_tag_server` table, and that this is an OUTER join, it's not at all clear why this table would be included in the query at all.

And no, LEFT JOIN does not mean what you said it means.

---

Q: *Left outer should join only if it has a matching record and otherwise return null, right?*

A: No. That's not what LEFT JOIN means. A LEFT JOIN will return all rows from the table on the left side, along with matching rows from the right side, just like an INNER JOIN. But with the LEFT JOIN, if there's a row from the left side that doesn't have a matching row from the right side, the row from the left is returned.  Yes, when that happens, the columns from the rightside table will consist of NULL placeholders.

---

The `LIMIT` clause applies to the total *number of rows* returned in the resultset. It does not mean the number of distinct rows from a given table.

Comment: You beat me to the answer ;) this was indeed what was causing it without me realizing it!

Comment: @xorinzor I don't understand how this explains it. Is there something else that's processing the result, and removing duplicates? That isn't apparent from the question.

Comment: @Barmar my `left outer join` was creating for-each `@mcmodlist_servers` record, multiple `@mcmodlist_tag_server` records. My PHP code automatically merged these into a single array per-server however. Using a normal MySQL client (Navicat for example) it was showing the `actual` results that I got from MySQL. each of these duplicate rows influenced the `LIMIT` but was invisible to me because of my PHP code.